# RTL await waitFor vs await findBy*

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I'm not really understand how to use async method in RTL. In the [docs](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async) they said `findBy` method is combination of `getBy` and `waitFor`. Is there any specific case when to use one of it?

My case is:

1. Show input elements after success fetching data
2. Fire event change of each input
3. Fire event click on submit button

With this approach, my test always failed and return `Received length: 0`

```
render(<Component {...mockProps} />);
const inputs = await screen.findAllByRole('textbox');
expect(inputs).toHaveLength(5); //failed
```

But with this approach, my test get passed

```
render(<Component {...mockProps} />);
await waitFor(() => {
   const inputs = screen.getAllByRole('textbox');
   expect(inputs).toHaveLength(5); //passed
});
```

How to get passed test with the first approach?

Because i want to call async method again after the inputs shows, should i do this?

```
await waitFor(async () => {
   const inputs = screen.getAllByRole('textbox');
   expect(inputs).toHaveLength(5);

   const [input1, input2, ...etc] = inputs;
   fireEvent.change(input1, {target: {value: 'first'}};
   ...etc

  await waitFor(() => {
     expect(onSubmit).toHaveBeenCalled();
  })
});
```

Comment: looking over, the first test shouldn't fail. Can you add your component code? So we can try to simulate it...

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. My one works only with waitFor. Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

You can have separate `waitFor()`s like this:

```
await waitFor(async () => {
   const inputs = screen.getAllByRole('textbox');
   expect(inputs).toHaveLength(5);

   const [input1, input2, ...etc] = inputs;
   fireEvent.change(input1, {target: {value: 'first'}};
   ...etc


});
await waitFor(() => {
  expect(onSubmit).toHaveBeenCalled();
})
```

If you want to stick with the first approach, you can use a `findBy` *along with* and `getBy` so you wait for the element to exist before "getting" it:

```
render(<Component {...mockProps} />);
await screen.findAllByRole('textbox');
const inputs = screen.getAllByRole('textbox');
expect(inputs).toHaveLength(5);

const [input1, input2, ...etc] = inputs;
fireEvent.change(input1, {target: {value: 'first'}};
...etc

await waitFor(() => {
   expect(onSubmit).toHaveBeenCalled();
})
```